# Dojo Mouse event undefined Xpages

Tags: dojo, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a traditional web application, not `xpage` where there is only one `dialogbox` in use, *dlg.xsp* below is the source code

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" dojoForm="true" dojoParseOnLoad="true" dojoTheme="true">
       <xp:this.resources>
          <xp:dojoModule name="dijit.form.ComboBox"></xp:dojoModule>
          <xp:styleSheet href="/style_extra.css"></xp:styleSheet>
          <xp:styleSheet href="/docflow.css"></xp:styleSheet>
       </xp:this.resources>
       <xp:this.afterPageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.jobFamily = param["fam"];
    viewScope.jobProfile = param["prof"];
    viewScope.profileHayGrade = param["profHG"];
    viewScope.positionHayGrade = param["posHG"];}]]></xp:this.afterPageLoad>
       <div style="margin:5px">
       <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" tagName="h2" value="Position / Hay Grade change"></xp:text>
       <xp:panel styleClass="divRow">
          <xp:label value="Job Family" id="lblJobFamily" for="ccJobFamily"></xp:label>
          <xp:comboBox id="ccJobFamily" value="#{viewScope.jobFamily}" dojoType="dijit.form.ComboBox">
             <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
                <xp:dojoAttribute name="selectOnClick" value="true"></xp:dojoAttribute>
                <xp:dojoAttribute name="highlightMatch" value="all"></xp:dojoAttribute>
             </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
             <xp:selectItem itemLabel=" "></xp:selectItem>
             <xp:selectItems>
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:@DbColumn("", "vwLkupJobFamilies", 1)}]]></xp:this.value>
             </xp:selectItems>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial"refreshId="divJobProfile">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.jobProfile = "";
                viewScope.profileHayGrade = "";
                viewScope.positionHayGrade = "";
                }]]></xp:this.action>
             </xp:eventHandler>
          </xp:comboBox>
       </xp:panel>
       <xp:panel id="divJobProfile" styleClass="divRow">
          <xp:panel id="divJobProfileInner">
             <xp:this.dataContexts>
                <xp:dataContext var="jobProfileList">
                   <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:try {
        var lkUp = @DbLookup("", "vwLkupJobFamilies", viewScope.jobFamily, 2);
        if(lkUp == null) lkUp = "";
        return lkUp;
    } catch(e) { return ""} }]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:dataContext>
                <xp:dataContext var="jobProfiles">
                   <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:try {
                            return @Trim(@Left(jobProfileList, "#"))
                } catch(e) { return ""} }]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:dataContext>
                <xp:dataContext var="jobHayGrades">
                   <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:try {
                            return @Trim(@Right(jobProfileList, "#"))
                } catch(e) { return ""} }]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:dataContext>
             </xp:this.dataContexts>
             <xp:label value="Job Profile" id="lblJobProfile"></xp:label>
             <xp:comboBox id="ccJobProfile" value="#{viewScope.jobProfile}" dojoType="dijit.form.ComboBox">
                <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
                   <xp:dojoAttribute name="selectOnClick" value="true"></xp:dojoAttribute>
                   <xp:dojoAttribute name="highlightMatch" value="all"></xp:dojoAttribute>
                </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
                <xp:selectItem itemLabel=" "></xp:selectItem>
                <xp:selectItems>
                   <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:jobProfiles}]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:selectItems>
                <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="divHayGrade">
                   <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var newHayGrade = @Replace(viewScope.jobProfile, jobProfiles, jobHayGrades);
    viewScope.profileHayGrade = newHayGrade;
    viewScope.positionHayGrade = newHayGrade;
    }]]></xp:this.action>
                </xp:eventHandler>
             </xp:comboBox>
             <xp:panel id="divHayGrade" styleClass="divRow">
                <xp:label value="Job Profile Hay Grade" id="lblProfileHayGrade" for="ccProfileHayGrade"></xp:label>
                <xp:inputText id="ccProfileHayGrade" readonly="true" value="#{viewScope.profileHayGrade}"></xp:inputText>
                <xp:panel styleClass="divRow">
                   <xp:label value="Position Hay Grade" id="lblPosHayGrade" for="ccPosHayGrade"></xp:label>
                   <xp:comboBox id="ccPosHayGrade" dojoType="dijit.form.ComboBox" value="#{viewScope.positionHayGrade}">
                      <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
                         <xp:dojoAttribute name="selectOnClick" value="true"></xp:dojoAttribute>
                         <xp:dojoAttribute name="highlightMatch" value="all"></xp:dojoAttribute>
                      </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
                      <xp:selectItem itemLabel=" "></xp:selectItem>
                      <xp:selectItems>
                         <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:@DbLookup("","parmdoc","Hay Grades","choice", "[FailSilent]")}]]></xp:this.value>
                      </xp:selectItems>
                      <xp:eventHandler event="onChange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="divHayGrade"></xp:eventHandler></xp:comboBox>
                </xp:panel>
                <xp:button id="btnSubmit" value="OK" styleClass="input_button">
                   <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
                      <xp:this.script><![CDATA[var fam="#{javascript:viewScope.jobFamily}";
          var prof="#{javascript:viewScope.jobProfile}";
          var profHG="#{javascript:viewScope.profileHayGrade}";
          var posHG="#{javascript:viewScope.positionHayGrade}";
          if(window.opener.submitProfileDialog(fam, prof, profHG, posHG))window.close();]]></xp:this.script>
                   </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:button>
                <xp:button id="button1" value="Cancel" styleClass="input_button">
                   <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
                      <xp:this.script><![CDATA[window.close();]]></xp:this.script>
                   </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:button>
             </xp:panel>
          </xp:panel>
       </xp:panel>
       </div>
    </xp:view>
```

The `xpage` works fine in chrome but in IE it gives the error

> Mouse event' is undefined.

The `xpage` worked on Domino 9 FP 8 failing on Domino 10 FP 4

Any hint to fix the issue is highly appreciated.

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

Strange, problem unknown to me...

Try to add a polyfill to a client-side script library: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent#Polyfill